# Categorizing data from DB2

Tags: jdbc, db2, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using a jdbcQuery as my datasource for the Extension Library Data View control to pull DB2 data and the page throws an error 500 when I use DB2 column names in the categoryColumn and/or summaryColumn columnName or value properties, but not the extraColumns.  I can understand why this might occur for the categoryColumn because the DB2 column isn't categorized, but would have thought the DB2 columns were considered summary columns.  Anyway, is there another control I can use or some hack method to make columns appear categorized when the column from the datasource isn't?

Domino 8.5.3FP3
Extension Library 9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
DB2 V10.1 for z/OS

Comment: Quick answer: repeat controls + sections...

Comment: @TimTripcony
Can you provide a snippet of code because I understand repeats some, but have never used a section.  I took two stabs at it using the pieces of code added as separate comments.  The first one is close to what I need, but the section header has each column value instead of just a unique value.

Comment: Snippet#1
`<xp:repeat
id="repeat1"
rows="30"
var="collRowData"
value="#{jdbcQuery1}">
 <xp:section
 id="section1"
 initClosed="false">
  <xp:this.header>
   <![CDATA[#{javascript:@JdbcDbColumn("db2","TECH.TBSCRA_DEMO","MBR_ACCESS_NBR")}]]>
  </xp:this.header>
   <xp:table style="width:100.0%; margin-left:30px;">
    <xp:tr>
     <xp:td>
      <xp:text
       escape="true"
       id="computedField2"
       value="#{collRowData.MBR_FIRST_NM}">
      </xp:text>
     </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
   </xp:table>
 </xp:section>
</xp:repeat>`

Comment: Snippet#2
`<xp:section
id="section1"
initClosed="false">
 <xp:this.header>
  <![CDATA[#{javascript:@JdbcDbColumn("db2","TECH.TBSCRA_DEMO","MBR_ACCESS_NBR")}]]>
 </xp:this.header>
 <xp:repeat
 id="repeat1"
 rows="30"
 var="collRowData"
 value="#{jdbcQuery1}">
  <xp:table style="width:100.0%; margin-left:30px;">
   <xp:tr>
    <xp:td>
     <xp:text
     escape="true"
     id="computedField2"
     value="#{collRowData.MBR_FIRST_NM}">
     </xp:text>
    </xp:td>
   </xp:tr>
  </xp:table>
 </xp:repeat>
</xp:section>`

Comment: I have been playing with trying to compute the value for the Section Header and even using database.getServer() I still get 4 sections instead of just one which is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: This **[blog article](http://www.eknori.de/2011-04-05/xpages-categorized-view-and-multiple-partial-refresh/)** from Ulrich Krause, has almost gotten me where I need to be.  All I have left to do is figure out how to get the second repeat to display my data elements from DB2 using the values from the first repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first repeat should contain the column headers, images to identify categoization, computed category value, and second repeat.  The datasource for the second repeat is making a new SQL call to pull in your specific fields based off the categorized value from the first repeat.  The field values are concatenated together so that they can be parsed for each of my computed fields.  My [blog](http://www.xpagesnewbie.wordpress.com) will show more detail with screenshots.  Screenshot shows categorized values on my XPage that are explained by code sample.
[image]

```
<xp:panel xp:key="facetMiddle">
 <xp:table>
  <xp:tr>
   <xp:td></xp:td>
  </xp:tr>
  <xp:repeat
   var="collRowData"
   value="#{jdbcQuery1}">  //name of XPage datasource
   <xp:tr>
    <xp:td>
     <xp:panel id="mainpanel">
      <xp:image
       id="image1"
       style="height:16.0px;width:16.0px"
       rendered="#{jav`enter code here`ascript:
        context.getSubmittedValue()=='hide' || 
        context.getSubmittedValue()== null;}">
        <xp:this.url><![CDATA[#{javascript:"/.ibmxspres/domino/icons/vwicn096.gif"}]]></xp:this.url>
         <xp:eventHandler
          event="onclick"
          submit="false">
          <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var visibility = 'show';
           XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:mainpanel}", {
           params: {'$$xspsubmitvalue': visibility}, 
           onComplete: function () {
           XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:secondpanel}", {
           params: {'$$xspsubmitvalue': visibility}});}});]]></xp:this.script>
         </xp:eventHandler>
      </xp:image>
      <xp:image
       id="image2"
       style="height:16.0px;width:16.0px"
       rendered="#{javascript:context.getSubmittedValue()=='show'}">
        <xp:this.url><![CDATA[#{javascript:"/.ibmxspres/domino/icons/vwicn097.gif"}]]></xp:this.url>
         <xp:eventHandler
          event="onclick"
          submit="false">
           <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var visibility = 'hide';
            XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:mainpanel}", {
            params: {'$$xspsubmitvalue': visibility}, 
            onComplete: function () {
            XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:secondpanel}", {
            params: {'$$xspsubmitvalue': visibility}});}});]]></xp:this.script>
         </xp:eventHandler>
      </xp:image>
      <xp:text
       escape="true"
       id="computedField2"
       style="margin-left:5.0px;font-weight:bold">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (collRowData[0]) {
          collRowData[0] }
         else {
          '- not categorized -'}}]]>
        </xp:this.value>
      </xp:text>
     </xp:panel>
     <xp:panel id="secondpanel">
      <xp:repeat
       var="character"
       rendered="#{javascript:context.getSubmittedValue()== 'show'}">
       <xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:
         var sql = "Select MBR_FIRST_NM, MBR_LAST_NM from TECH.TBSCRA_DEMO where MBR_ACCESS_NBR = '" + collRowData[0] + "'"; //single quote is before and after collRowData[0]
         var rs = @JdbcExecuteQuery("db2",sql);
         var fName;
         var lName;
         while(rs.next()) {
         //Get the data from the row using the column name
         fName = rs.getString("MBR_FIRST_NM");
         lName = rs.getString("MBR_LAST_NM");
        }
        return fName + "," + lName}]]></xp:this.value>
       <xp:table>
        <xp:tr>
         <xp:td>
          <xp:text
           escape="true"
           id="firstname">
           <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
           var nm = @Explode(character,",");
            if (character) {
             nm[0] }
            else {
             '- not categorized -'}}]]></xp:this.value>
          </xp:text>
         </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
       </xp:table>
      </xp:repeat>
     </xp:panel>
    </xp:td>
   </xp:tr>
  </xp:repeat>
 </xp:table>
</xp:panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [Category Bean](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Category%20Bean) project might help. At least you can make your own bean based on it.

Comment: I checked out that project and not knowing alot about beans not sure if it would work.  I did create a new discussion asking that and have yet to get a response.  However, I was finally able to get something to actually work where the values are displayed.  Doing a sort on other columns is the next task.

Comment: (According that question in project discussion) I am sure this bean will NOT work with DB2 right on. I've pointed at it because you should look into its sources and alter it to get data from JDBC instead of native Domino view. So you have to write your own bean, based on its sources.

Comment: Thank you for the added comment.  Beans are something I have yet to really dive into.